# PHP parameterized query using mysql_query function AND security?

Tags: php, mysql

### Disclaimer

Please excuse my ignorance, I've written C# for more than 12 years now and I'm quite comfortable with the .NET framework and OO programming, and I've got a good background in enterprise applications, but this is my first bout with PHP.

### Question

Alright, so I'm trying to figure out how to issue a `prepare` using the `mysql_query` function and I'm not able to put two and two together. Right now I connect like this:

```
mysql_connect('xxx.x.x.x:xxxx', 'x', 'x');
mysql_select_db('x');
```

And that is succeeding.

Now, I want to insert some data and so I'm looking at the `mysql_query` function and just can't figure out how to send a **parameterized query** to prevent SQL Injection. My code currently looks like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (email, password, ...)
    VALUES (:email, :password, :...)
```

**But how do I pass the array of values to it?**

### Additional Question

**If I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string` on every value that I receive via user input, do I need to worry about issuing parameterized queries?**

Comment: Rule # 0, you don't use `mysql_` functions because they're [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). You can use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: @njk, now that is some good information! Love the Blog BTW, bookmarked! Now, make that an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment, mysql_ functions are being deprecated. You should use mysqli_ or PDO which allows for parameter binding to prevent against SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

You are best off using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (or mysqli) to do this. However, you will find examples using PDO, mysqli, adodb and other on the [bobby-tables website](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html). I suggest you read the PDO doco for [bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), which will get you what you need.